# ¿Cómo encontrar qué pares de divisas de una lista tienen ausentes ambas divisas en todas las celdas de una columna en Python? Relacionado a Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, filtro, depuración

Suponga que tiene la siguiente lista llamada `currency_trading_pairs` con los siguientes elementos:

```
currency_trading_pairs = ['USD/CAD', 'EUR/USD', 'GBP/USD', 'NZD/USD', 'AUD/USD', 
                          'USD/JPY', 'EUR/CAD', 'EUR/AUD', 'EUR/JPY', 'EUR/GBP',
                          'AUD/CAD', 'GBP/JPY', 'CHF/JPY', 'AUD/JPY', 'AUD/NZD']
```

Ahora, suponga que tiene el siguiente marco de datos llamado `filtered_df` con los siguientes datos:

```
    Time    Currency    Volatility expected        Event
24  04:30     GBP   Low Volatility Expected        Inflation Expectations
25  05:00     EUR   High Volatility Expected       EU Leaders Summit  
26  05:10     EUR   Low Volatility Expected        Italian 15-Year BTP Auction
27  05:10     EUR   Low Volatility Expected        Italian 3-Year BTP Auction
28  05:10     EUR   Low Volatility Expected        Italian 7-Year BTP Auction
29  06:00     EUR   Low Volatility Expected        Spanish Consumer Confidence
30  06:30     INR   Low Volatility Expected        Bank Loan Growth
31  06:30     INR   Low Volatility Expected        Deposit Growth
32  06:30     INR   Low Volatility Expected        FX Reserves, USD
33  07:00     INR   Low Volatility Expected        Cumulative Industrial Production (Jan)
34  07:00     INR   Low Volatility Expected        Industrial Production (YoY) (Jan)
35  07:00     INR   Low Volatility Expected        Manufacturing Output (MoM) (Jan)
36  07:00     BRL   Moderate Volatility Expected   CPI (YoY) (Feb)
37  07:00     BRL   Moderate Volatility Expected   CPI (MoM) (Feb)
38  08:06     BRL   Moderate Volatility Expected   Brazilian IPCA Inflation Index SA (MoM)(Feb)
39  08:30     CAD   Low Volatility Expected        Capacity Utilization Rate (Q4)
40  08:30     CAD   High Volatility Expected       Employment Change (Feb)
41  08:30     CAD   Low Volatility Expected        Full Employment Change (Feb)
42  08:30     CAD   Low Volatility Expected        Part Time Employment Change (Feb)
43  08:30     CAD   Low Volatility Expected        Participation Rate (Feb)
44  08:30     CAD   Moderate Volatility Expected   Unemployment Rate (Feb)
```

¿Cómo podría encontrar **qué pares de divisas (elementos)** de `currency_trading_pairs` (lista) **tienen ambas monedas faltantes en todas las celdas de la columna** `Currency` de la variable `filtered_df` para que pueda obtener el siguiente resultado en una variable llamada `the_missing_pairs` ?:

```
the_missing_pairs = ['NZD/USD', 'AUD/USD', 'USD/JPY', 'CHF/JPY', 'AUD/JPY', 'AUD/NZD']
```

*Explicación adicional: básicamente, asegurarse de que todos los nombres de divisas en* `the_missing_pairs` *no aparezcan en ninguna de las celdas de la columna* `Currency` *de la variable* `filtered_df`.

**Yo intenté** convertir `currency_trading_pairs` en un objeto Serie. Luego partir las strings del la serie por `/` para usar `explode`, luego usar `isin` y finalmente `groupby(level=0)` + `any` para producir la máscara perfecta. Así:

```
ctp = pd.Series(currency_trading_pairs)
the_missing_pairs = ctp[~ctp.str.split('/').explode().isin(df['Currency']).groupby(level=0).any()].tolist()
```

Sin embargo, al final la variable `the_missing_pairs` tiene exactamente los mismos valores de `currency_trading_pairs` lo que me da a entender que no funciona como debería, sí no es mucha molestia, quisiera saber ¿por qué no funciona? Usé Python `3.9.6` para correr todo el código de arriba.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Puedes utilizar `list comprehension` para comparar tu lista de la columna `Currency` con tu lista `currency_trading_pairs`

```
the_missing_pairs = [x for x in currency_trading_pairs if not any(b in x for b in currency)]
```

Esto te devuelve una lista de los elementos de `currency_trading_pairs` que no contienen ningún elemento de la lista `currency`

Para no hacer todo el `dataframe`, en el ejemplo siguiente cree una lista `currency` con los valores que aparecen en tu pregunta. Esta lista la puedes obtener directamente de tu columna en caso de tener más datos.

```
currency_trading_pairs = ['USD/CAD', 'EUR/USD', 'GBP/USD', 'NZD/USD', 'AUD/USD', 
                          'USD/JPY', 'EUR/CAD', 'EUR/AUD', 'EUR/JPY', 'EUR/GBP',
                          'AUD/CAD', 'GBP/JPY', 'CHF/JPY', 'AUD/JPY', 'AUD/NZD']

currency = ['GBP', 'EUR', 'INR', 'BRL', 'CAD']

the_missing_pairs = [x for x in currency_trading_pairs if not any(b in x for b in currency)]
```

Al hacer `print()` en `the_missing_pairs`, devuelve:

```
['NZD/USD', 'AUD/USD', 'USD/JPY', 'CHF/JPY', 'AUD/JPY', 'AUD/NZD']
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, pero al intentar tu solución sigo obtenido el mismo problema que obtuve con la solución que usé en Python `3.9.6`.

Comment: @NoahVerner, ¿Quieres decir que al ejecutar el código de la respuesta `the_missing_pairs` tiene lo mismo que `currency_trading_pairs`? Yo probé con python 3.8, 3.9.6 y 3.9.7, funciona en los tres  casos

Comment: Aguarda, creo que se debe al hecho de que cuando convierto a conjunto la columna `Currency` de la `filtered_df` los elementos añadidos al conjunto con dos espacios demás, por ejemplo al añadir `EUR` lo añade como `  EUR`, ¿sabes cómo puedo arreglar esto? quiero decir, cómo decirle que borre las 2 primeros caracteres de cada elemento antes de añadirlos al conjunto.

Comment: Usa esto `df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()` esto va a eliminar espacios en blanco al inicio y al final de todas las celdas de tu `dataframe` Si deseas hacerlo únicamente para una columna entonces en lugar de `df.columns` utiliza `df['ColumnaDeseada']` Donde ColumnaDeseada lo debes sustituir por el nombre de la columna que quieres "limpiar"

Comment: Mil gracias, en definitiva sí era lo que mencioné, tuve que usar `strip_cells = filtered_df['Currency'].str.strip()` luego `filtered_df.update(strip_cells)` para poder finalmente obtener la solución que mencionas.

Comment: @NoahVerner si haces `filtered_df['Currency'] = filtered_df['Currency'].str.strip()` debería funcionar en una sola línea

Comment: Gracias, sí funciona, aunque la consola retorna una advertencia que dice: `SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead` ¿está la sentencia usada obsoleta?

Comment: Decidí usar `pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None  # default='warn'`, según esta respuesta https://stackoverflow.com/a/20627316/16467154. Y ya, GG IZI.